# Dark Tower Movie?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Over a year ago, I heard they were going to make a Dark Tower movie, possible starring Javier Bardem. What is the latest with the plan to make a movie(s) out of Stephen King's Dark Tower series?

Comment: Speculation about future releases is off-topic here. For more information, see [this meta post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates).

Comment: Speculation over a future release

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_series_film_adaptation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is still hope!
The project stalled for a while, JJ Abrams and others turned it down because it was too huge. But Ron Howard and Brian Grazer are working up two plans. One option is three movies with TV mini-series in between. Starring Russell Crowe as Roland. Supposedly they have new funding from some software mogul. Anyway that's what I heard back in March 2013.

Comment: Well, they are doing one now, and aside from their choice of actor for Roland, it looks ridiculous.